# Is there a better way to express this in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Suppose I have clients and services of the following schema:

```sql
create table client (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

create table service (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    client_id INT NOT NULL,
    status varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

And the requirement is to select all clients which have **all** their services deleted (status = 'DELETED'). What would be the best approach?

My try is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT service.client_id
FROM service
WHERE service.id NOT IN (SELECT service.id FROM service s WHERE s.status <> 'DELETED' AND s.client_id = service.client_id);
```

But it only selects client_id, probably need some join.

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u3xMpxKVrrJc8uq27rrfV6/1)

Comment: Whenever I see a subselect, I see a `JOIN` waiting to happen.

Comment: Can you show how it's solved via JOINS please?

Comment: @tadman: I don't. But whenever I see `DISTINCT` my first thought this is that someone might mistakenly have used a join instead of the appropriate subquery (`[NOT] IN/EXISTS`). (This is not the case in Sebastians query, though. The `DISTINCT` is just superfluous. The idea to use a subquery is good. Stu's answer shows how to apply it with `NOT EXISTS`. The same is possible with `NOT IN`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you need a *not exists*

```
SELECT id, name
FROM client c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM service s 
  WHERE s.client_id = c.id AND status != 'DELETED'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also need the `service.id`, use a combination of join and exists.

```sql
SELECT c.id AS client_id, c.name, s.id AS service_id
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.id = s.client_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM service s2
    WHERE s2.client_id = c.id AND s2.status <> 'DELETED'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count existing services and just filter using `HAVING`

```sql
SELECT service.client_id, SUM(IF(service.status <> 'DELETED', 1, 0)) existing_services
FROM service
GROUP BY service.client_id
HAVING existing_services = 0;
```

```
| client_id | existing_services |
| --------- | ----------------- |
| 2         | 0                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use exists

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table client (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

create table service (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    client_id INT NOT NULL,
    status varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

# Client 1
insert into client(id, name) VALUES (1, "client 1");
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (0, 1, 'DELETED');
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (1, 1, 'ACTIVE');

# Client 2
insert into client(id, name) VALUES (2, "client 2");
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (2, 2, 'DELETED');
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (3, 2, 'DELETED');

# Client 3
insert into client(id, name) VALUES (3, "client 3");
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (4, 3, 'DELETED');
insert into service(id, client_id, status) VALUES (5, 3, 'ACTIVE');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT service.client_id
FROM service
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM service s WHERE s.status <> 'DELETED' AND s.client_id = service.client_id);
```

| client_id |
| --- |
| 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u3xMpxKVrrJc8uq27rrfV6/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` and `having` clauses, with the condition that the total number of services equals the total number of services with status *DELETED*:

```
select c.*
from client c
inner join (
  select client_id
  from service
  group by client_id
  having count(case when status = 'DELETED' then 1 end) = count(*)
) as s on s.client_id = c.id
```

Result :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | client 2 |

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQRLbQfAzsaSfq2fy3ENnz/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with a JOIN:

```
SELECT  cl.id, cl.name
FROM client cl
left join service sr on sr.client_id=cl.id and sr.status<>'DELETED'
where sr.id is null
```